# Comparing two dictionary values gives me an NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, crash, nsdictionary

I have a for loop that iterates through dictionaries within a dictionary, trying to find one that has a key that matches a key from a completely separate dictionary.

```
for (id rDCKey in rootDictCopy)
{
    tempHouseNumber = rDCKey;

    if ([[[rootDictCopy objectForKey:rDCKey] objectForKey:@"RandomUniqueIdentifier"] isEqual:[[routePathRootDictCopy objectForKey:houseNumber] objectForKey:@"RandomUniqueIdentifier"]])
    {
        NSLog(@"done");
        goto DONE;
    }
}
```

When both values are equal to nothing, it's fine, and everything passes. But the moment they have a value (which is always a 256 character long NSString), it crashes, giving me this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa000000333939394'
```

I have no clue what's up, and any help would be appreciated.

I can give more code if necessary.

Thanks.

Update: I updated my for loop to check for types, but the same problem occurs.

Update 2: Changed || to &&

```
for (id rDCKey in rootDictCopy)
{
    tempHouseNumber = rDCKey;

    if ([[rootDictCopy objectForKey:rDCKey] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]] && [[routePathRootDictCopy objectForKey:houseNumber] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]])
    {
        if ([[[rootDictCopy objectForKey:rDCKey] objectForKey:@"RandomUniqueIdentifier"] isEqual:[[routePathRootDictCopy objectForKey:houseNumber] objectForKey:@"RandomUniqueIdentifier"]])
        {
            NSLog(@"done");
            goto DONE;
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
    }             
}
```

Comment: You are probably calling objectForKey on NSString object instead of NSDictionary object. Verify contents of rootDictCopy. You can add type checking. :P

Comment: @AmitTandel Just checked, they are both proper NSMutableDictionaries, and show up in the logs as would an NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Can you send, what logs are showing for "rootDictCopy" and "routePathRootDictCopy" ?

Comment: You wrote your "safe test" with `||`, but both conditions should be true!. Use "&&" insteand, and if it fails, test it one by one to check which one fails.

Comment: @Larme I looked into it, and for some reason, rootDictCopy is sometimes a string, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

> reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0xa000000333939394'

Exception occurred because you called `objectForKey` method with an object type  `NSTaggedPointerString`

Before compare you should check type of your data.
You can do as below:

```
if ( [obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {
  // is a NSDictionary
  // do further action like get objectForKey, compare ..
} else {
  // you don't got what you want -> print error log or something like that
}
```

And your code should be like below:

```
for (id rDCKey in rootDictCopy)
{
    tempHouseNumber = rDCKey;
    // TODO: 
    // check if rootDictCopy is a NSDictionary (if needed)
    // check if routePathRootDictCopy is a NSDictionary (if needed)
    // check if [rootDictCopy objectForKey:rDCKey] is a NSDictionary
    // check if [routePathRootDictCopy objectForKey:houseNumber] is a NSDictionary
    if ([[[rootDictCopy objectForKey:rDCKey] objectForKey:@"RandomUniqueIdentifier"] isEqual:[[routePathRootDictCopy objectForKey:houseNumber] objectForKey:@"RandomUniqueIdentifier"]])
    {
        NSLog(@"done");
        goto DONE;
    }
}
```

Note: My answer will help your code work without crash but your should find why you got unexpected object type here. And how to sure you alway recevied `NSMutableDictionary` object, that is the best solution!

Comment: I tried your suggestion to check the types, and it passes that with no problem. The same issue occurs when I get to the next line though.

Comment: update the code that you tried to your question please. 
so i can easy to figure out what happening with your code.

Comment: I see, the problem is you must USE `&&` NOT `||` when check type of your two objects.

Comment: I changed it, and now I'm getting a mixture of "done" (successful check between the two dictionaries) and "ERROR" (at least one item is not an NSMutableDictionary) in my log. Then, at the end, it finishes with the exact same error I started with. How does it make sense that something would change types during a for loop?

Comment: (at least one item is not an NSMutableDictionary)  -> My answer will help your code work without crash but your should find why you got unexpected object type here. And how to sure you always recevied NSMutableDictionary object, that is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

As users Nhat Dinh, Amit Tandel and Larme suggested, some dictionaries within rootDictCopy had been transformed into an NSString earlier in the code. I fixed that, making those dictionaries remain dictionaries, and I no longer receive that error. Thanks for everyone's help!